# React Js API call Unit Test Case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, react-testing

I m trying to write test cases for my API I call but I don't know what I am doing wrong that I am getting errors like this.

**car.test.js**

```
import { getCar } from "../Service/MainScreen/Cars/Car";

describe("Car  API Call function", () => {
  test("it should pass the test", () => {
    const testData = {
      id: 186,
      plate_number: "WW12345",
      status_display: "Aktywny",
      driver_name: "Jakub Nowak",
      driver_id: 181,
      created_at: "2021-08-12T09:07:30Z",
      vin: "WBADM123123123123",
      brand: "Ford",
      model: "Focus",
      "Brand-Model": "Ford/Focus",
      production: "2016",
      registration: "01-12-2020",
      insurance_date: "06-06-2023",
      has_registration_docs: true,
      has_policy_status: true,
      has_certificate: true,
      has_green_card: true,
      has_vehicle_card: true,
      has_car_picture: true,
      fleet_entry: "20-04-2018",
      monitoring_start: "12-08-2021",
      status: "Aktywny",
      Estimaed_distance: 29500,
      Estimaed_fuel: 1475,
      average_fuel: 5,
      claim: 1,
      cost: 1000,
    };

    const response = { json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(testData) };
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(response);

    return getCar().then((data) => {
      expect(data[0]).toEqual(testData);
    });
  });
});
```

**GetCar**
import config from "../../../Config/Api";

```
export async function getCar() {
  return fetch(config.fakeapi.car, config.fakeHead)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((reject) => console.log(reject));
}
```

Here is the error in the image that I have attached can someone please help me to resolve my test case that I can write also for another API call [image].

Answer (score 0):

`testData` is NOT array, that's why `data[0]` gives you `undefined`. It should be:

```js
const response = { json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(testData) };
global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(response);

return getCar().then((data) => {
  expect(data).toEqual(testData);
});
```